# MongoDB java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an issue where it says my connection is closed, but I have never closed it. It happens when I try to get a collection. Below is the code needed, the only other time I use MongoDB is to get a different collection and loop through some documents.

````java
 MongoCollection<Document> playerdb = db1.getCollection("Player");


        Document playerDoc =  playerdb.find(eq("uuid", p.getUniqueId().toString()))
                .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("guildName")))
                .first();

        playerdb.updateOne(playerDoc, Updates.set("guildName", name))
    ```

The error is on the .first() method.
````

Answer (score 0):

I think  MongoClient might be closed. before using document